# Xcode do not suggestion (autocomplete) code

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

I have swift project in XCode 6. Something happened to my project that make my suggestion (autocomplete) doesn't work.

> 1. It's problem with my current project. Other projects works good.
> 2. I've tried to delete Derived Data.
> 3. Reinstall XCode
> 4. Deleted .workspace in project
> 5. Tried "Header path".

I searching answer and nothing of it do not work.

One more: after delete of derived data when Xcode RE-indexing autocomplete is WORK. But when it finished autocomplete do not work again. It's something with workspace?

Answer (score 4):

1. Clear derived data.
2. Under build settings, select Always Search User Paths to "YES".
3. Clean the project.

Answer (score 1):

When troubleshooting this and reading other SO articles, I ended up setting the `Defines Module` build setting to **true**.  This stopped all autocompletion in my swift files.

The solution for me was to set the `Defines Module` build setting to **false**

Hope this helps you!